# Google App Engine & Google Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I try to enable Cloud Storage for my GAE app. I read in the docs that:

> Add the service account as a project editor to the Google APIs Console
>   project that the bucket belongs to. For information about permissions
>   in Cloud Storage, see Scopes and Permissions on the Cloud Storage
>   documentation.

However when I try to the service account to Team Members at the API Console I get the following message:

User ****@****.gserviceaccount.com may not be added to Project "****". Only members from domain ***.com may be added.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a custom domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you created the API console project with an Apps account (one @yourdomain.com), the project is automatically treated as an Apps project, and only users from your domain can be added to it.

To avoid this, create a new project using a @gmail.com account, and then add all the developers you want to have access to it. You can then remove the @gmail.com account.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a google group to make this work for your custom domain.

1. In the cpanel for managing your domain go to the 'groups' tab and add a new group that will be for your app.
2. Add the service account *.gserviceaccount.com as a member to the group that you have created.
3. Add the group to the team for your project at https://code.google.com/apis/console.